# Javascript library to use zkSnark circuit

Tags: javascript, zksnark, zero-knowledge

I would like to generate the proofs for zkSnarks on client side and therefore would need a library in javascript that helps to read a circuit and generate proofs. I found one combination here which seems promising: https://github.com/iden3/circom (for creating circuits) and the corresponding library to use in javascript here: https://github.com/iden3/snarkjs

Unfortunately, I cannot find any documentation regarding Circom anywhere except for one tutorial on their GitHub page. I would like to know if there exists any detailed documentation for it or when will it be available.

If there is any other library that serves my purpose, I would be happy to know about it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly, there is very little documentation about Circom.
However, you may want to take a look at [base Circom library by ABDK](https://github.com/abdk-consulting/abdk-libraries-circom/tree/master/base).  It contains many small Circom templates, quite well documented.